# error TS2339: Property 'funcionarios' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting this error in Angular CLI when the project start to run:

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(44,37): error TS2339: Property 'funcionarios' does not exist on type 'Object'.
>   src/app/app.component.ts(51,36): error TS2339: Property 'funcionario' does not exist on type 'Object'.

How can I solve this?

This is the Angular app.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

@Injectable()
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'Angular + Symfony CRUD'; 



private funcionarioForm: FormGroup;
funcionario: any;
funcionarios: any;  

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getFuncionarios();
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.funcionarioForm = new FormGroup({
        'nome': new FormControl(),
        'matricula': new FormControl(),
        'email': new FormControl()
      });
}

// Adiciona um novo funcionario
adicionarFuncionario(funcionarioForm: NgForm) {      
    this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/funcionarios', funcionarioForm.value).subscribe(res => {
        this.getFuncionarios();
        funcionarioForm.reset();
    }, err => {
        console.log('Ocorreu um erro');
    });
}

getFuncionarios() {        
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/funcionarios').subscribe(res => {
        this.funcionarios = res.funcionarios;
    });
}


showFuncionario(id) {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/funcionarios/' + id).subscribe(res => {
        this.funcionario = res.funcionario;
        this.funcionarioForm.patchValue({
            id: this.funcionario.id,
            nome: this.funcionario.nome,
            matricula: this.funcionario.matricula,
            email: this.funcionario.email
        });
    });
}

deletarFuncionario(id) {
    this.http.delete('http://127.0.0.1:8000/funcionarios/' + id).subscribe(res => {
        console.log('Product Deleted and refresh Table');
        this.getFuncionarios();
    }, err => {
        console.log('Ocorreu um erro');
    });
}

atualizarFuncionario(id) {
    this.http.put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/funcionarios/' + id, this.funcionarioForm.value).subscribe(res => {
        console.log('Product Updated and refresh table');
        this.getFuncionarios();
    }, err => {
        console.log('Ocorreu um erro');
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this: `this.funcionarios = res.funcionarios;` is correct? Does `funcionarios` exist on 'res'?

Comment: It seems your "res" from the subscription doesn't have the "funcionaro" property... try to debug what is inside your subscription.